# Android equivalent of Swift's HKObserverQuery?

Tags: android, ios, healthkit, google-fit

Hi I'm want to collect user health data. In iOS we have HKObserverQuery to observe.So when ever there is a change in health data for example, change in step count it will wake our app. Is there any thing similar in android for live updates. So I can setup monitoring for any changes.
I been scratching my head for few days. Thank you.

Comment: Please comment the reason for down votes.I can get some thing from that.

Answer (score 2):

## Broadcasts

Android apps can send or receive broadcast messages from the Android system and other Android apps, similar to the publish-subscribe design pattern. These broadcasts are sent when an event of interest occurs. For example, the Android system sends broadcasts when various system events occur, such as when the system boots up or the device starts charging. Apps can also send custom broadcasts, for example, to notify other apps of something that they might be interested in (for example, some new data has been downloaded).

> You Could Use LocalBroadcastManager for your  App when data changed it will called from your code
>
> Then Register Reciever in manifest
>
> send Broadcast locally fron your app to Broadcast Reciever when data changed in store Like HKObserverQuery

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a `CompletableFuture` class in java to do so. You can read about it in Java's documentation

Comment: Can you please provide me the link.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html

Comment: Above is the link

Comment: I think you didn't get my point. When working in health kit, when ever there is a change , it will automatically wake up our code. Is there similar function in android?

Comment: Yes dear, it has the ability to do so with this class in Java version 8

Comment: We don't know the source of update.  Then we cannot monitor using Completable Future.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162034/discussion-between-e-k-and-shridhar-sharma).

Comment: Ok, come in chat room